# Converting Mcrypt Rinjdael-128-CBC function to php-7.0

Tags: php, aes

I'm trying to do an ecrypt decrypt on php. An old function written by a colleague for the encryption and decryption using MCRYPT RINJDAEL-128-CBC is as follows.
Encrypt

```
        $key = pack('H*', $salt);    
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        return base64_encode($iv . $ciphertext);
    }
```

Decrypt

````
    $key = pack('H*', $salt);
    $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($encodedText);
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);
    $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);
}```

Due to php deprecating Mcrypt and only uses Openssl, how would I write a function that can do exactly the same?
````

Comment: Since you're using RINJDAEL-128 which is AES, you can use [`openssl_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) with `"AES-128-CBC"`.

Comment: Do I still use the mcrypt iv settings still?

Comment: No, use [`openssl_cipher_iv_length()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-cipher-iv-length.php) to get the IV size and use [`random_bytes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) as a CSPRNG.